# How to create multiple pages from single json files in Gatsby

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am new to node.js and react but I love gatsby.js. I have followed all the tutorials that I can find and it's such a great tool.

However one of the main reasons why I want to use it is I have a file json with 1000 different records in and I would like to generate a new page for each record.

I believe I have come to the conclusion that I need to learn more about the gatsby-node.js file and am aware of the following resource but are there any tutorials or other examples on this topic that maybe a little easier to follow:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs

Answer (score 19):

The example you were referring to should already give you a good idea. The basic concept is to import the JSON file, loop over it and run `createPage` for each of the items in your JSON source. So given an example source file like:

<sub>**pages.json**</sub>

```
[{
  "page": "name-1"
}, {
  "page": "name-2"
}]
```

You can then use the Node API to create pages for each:

<sub>**gatsby-node.js**</sub>

```
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./pages.json');

exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators }) => {
  const { createPage } = boundActionCreators;

  // Your component that should be rendered for every item in JSON.
  const template = path.resolve(`src/template.js`);

  // Create pages for each JSON entry.
  data.forEach(({ page }) => {
    const path = page;

    createPage({
      path,
      component: template,

      // Send additional data to page from JSON (or query inside template)
      context: {
        path
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: can you please write down  graphql  query  for template.js  ?