# How to create routes with params in gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to create a route that uses a slug as a parameter in my gatsby generated website.

I have a list of projects that sit on the route `/projects/<slug>`.

Usually with react router I would create a route like so:

```
<Route exact path='/projects/:project' component={Projects} />
```

It seems in gatsby, I have to create a new file under the `./pages` directory and that creates a new route. I have a page called `projects` where I try do a look up on the route param but only seem to get the 404 page.

```
// ./pages/projects.js

class SingleProject extends Component {

  state = {
    project: {}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const project = this.props.projects.find(project => project.slug === this.props.match.params.project)
    this.setState({project})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="single-project" >
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SingleProject;
```

How can I have routes with parameters in gatsby?

I have just come across [client only routes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/) but I guess these routes wont be statically generated.

I will have a predefined list of slugs so perhaps there is a way to create a page for each of the project slugs? I guess I could manually create a file within `./pages/projects/<slug>` foreach project I have?

Comment: Question name is misleading, as it is confused with Query parameters, maybe use variable instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use the `createPage` method that Gatsby gives you inside `gatsby-node.js`'s [`createPages`](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) API. There is [a guide](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#creating-pages-in-gatsby-nodejs) in the Gatsby documentation that shows you can achieve exactly this. [Here's an even simpler example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654140/6941627) from a similar question.

```
export const createPages = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  createPage({
    path: '/projects/hello-world',
    component: SingleProject,

    // Send additional data to page component
    context: {
      id: 'hello-world',
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.